# Firebase, can't delete User's record while remove user

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

when i remove the user, i cant remove him records. I know what locations will remove but when the user are deleted successfully, values is still in the database.

```
.....
final String useruid=""+user.getUid();

//auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
//user=auth.getCurrentUser();


 dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                if (user != null) {

                    user.delete()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profileinfos").child(useruid).removeValue();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("holograminfos").child(useruid).removeValue();


                                        Toast.makeText(Ayarlar.this, "Hesabınız başarılı bir şekilde silindi. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       dialog.dismiss();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(Ayarlar.this, LoginActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Ayarlar.this, "Bir Hata Meydana Geldi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }});
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Ayarlar.this, "Onaylamak için lütfen kutucuğu seçiniz.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return;
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: Thats my database.]

There is no exception.

Comment: are you getting this toast `"Hesabınız başarılı bir şekilde silindi.`?

Comment: yes. and i check the Authentication. User is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete it from the database first, then delete it from the authenticated console, try this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profileinfos").child(useruid).removeValue();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("holograminfos").child(useruid).removeValue();

    user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
     Toast.makeText(Ayarlar.this, "Hesabınız başarılı bir şekilde silindi. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   dialog.dismiss();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Ayarlar.this, LoginActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Ayarlar.this, "Bir Hata Meydana Geldi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }});
            }
```

Comment: I thinked this. But if user dont delete the user ? User's records will gone.  user.delete() must be successfully first. Or it could be  !isSuccessful() and only records is gone, user stays still online.

Comment: I think when u delete a `user`, this `final String useruid=""+user.getUid();` becomes null since there is no current user logged in anymore, so useruid will be null thus nothing gets deleted. That is why I said first in the database then in the authenticated console

Comment: No it was null but i fixed it. I added a Log.e("a",""+useruid) and Log is showing me the correct uid. the Log is inside the task.isSucces().

Comment: u added `Log.e("a",""+useruid)` inside `if(task.isSuccessful)`? Did you try the answer?

Comment: yes i did and i got the uid. Now i'm so confused. whats the problem.

Comment: did the answer work? As it should be deleted from the database and authenticated console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165324/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-australopithecus).